# How to make widgetized footer styles be inherited from body?

Tags: css

I'm making a WordPress site using the Thesis framework. It has a widgetized footer area. I expect to be changing all the font styles frequently and don't want to have to change them in a few places every time to make the footer widget styles match the body styles. Does anyone know how I can make the footers styles (h3, text, li, a href) be automatically inherited from what I've set for the body styles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The footer is a child of the body element. It **does** already inherit all the styles. Find and remove all the styles which are ruling out the inherited styles.
Tools like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) or [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) will help you to find these rules.

Comment: Oh, brilliant. No wonder I was starting to tear my hair out over this: Thesis puts the main formatting in a style.css and layout.css, and then all "custom" changes, additions and subtractions should be put in custom.css. We're told only to edit the custom.css (and custom_functions.php) to make any and all changes. I'd prefer to adhere to the intended structure by only changing the custom files. Any chance you can think of how I can do that?

Comment: I don’t own Thesis. How does it reference the style.css? If it is using `get_stylesheet_uri();` you can add a filter to `'stylesheet_uri'` and replace the URI with your stripped version.